# Recaptcha not working until I clear server cache

Tags: php, laravel, caching, recaptcha

I implemented Google's recaptcha on a website. However it seems that the recaptcha v2 doesn't work unless I clear server cache. Not sure why this is happening. It works fine for about an hour or 2 then it breaks where users cannot submit their entries. Any ideas how this can be solved? My website is roadmap2recovery.gov.tt

Answer (score 1):

You are currently rendering the reCAPTCHA widget on page load and then reset it when the user get's to the point. This can lead to unexpected behaviour.

I would recommend you to add a placeholder and manually render the widget when the user is rendering the final tab.

In your case:

```
<div id="recaptcha_widget"></div>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=explicit" async defer>
```

And in the `wizard_validation.js`:

```
if ($('li.last').hasClass('current')) {
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        grecaptcha.render('recaptcha_widget', {
           'sitekey' : 'your_site_key'
        });
    }, 100); // <-- maybe also set this a bit higher?
}
```